# SPSS: Switch server by syntax command

Tags: spss

Mostly, I run SPSS on a server. However, there are occasions, when it needs to be run locally. 
I didn't find a way to tell SPSS by syntax, whether it has to run on the server or locally. Any ideas how to solve that 'problem'?

Answer (score 1):

There is no SPSS syntax to do that.

There may be methods in scripting to do it. From the Python Reference Guide for SPSS Statistics, I see this:

```
GetLocalServer Method

Returns an SpssServerConf object representing the local computer.

Syntax
SpssServerConf=SpssClient.GetLocalServer()
```

That would be the first thing to try.

I guess you could start the server locally and then use the following in a `BEGIN .. END PROGRAM` block to run stuff on the server:

```
Example: Connecting to a Server Using a Saved Configuration

import SpssClient
SpssClient.StartClient()
ServerConfList = SpssClient.GetConfiguredServers()
for i in range(ServerConfList.Size()):
server = ServerConfList.GetItemAt(i)
if server.GetServerName()=="myservername":
server.ConnectWithSavedPassword()
SpssClient.StopClient()
```

- SpssClient.GetConfiguredServers() gets an SpssServerConfList object that provides access to the list of configured servers.
  -The GetItemAt method of an SpssServerConfList object returns the SpssServerConf object at the specified index. Index values start from 0 and represent the order in which the servers were added to the list.
- The ConnectWithSavedPassword method uses the connection information (domain, user ID, and password) to connect to the server.